# nothing happens SVG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have been practicing with javascript and canvas lately. I was working on some code using the canvas, when I reached a point where I could not implement what I wanted using canvas.
So I switched to SVG. I translated the canvas related code to svg, and gave it a try. Nothing was showing.
I have taken a little portion of the code and posted it here. Maybe you can tell me what I am missing, or what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>SVG</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
var agsvg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var esvg = agsvg.namespaceURI;

xl = 400;
yl = 400;
xmarg = 160;
ymarg = 280;
xw = xl + xmarg;
yh = yl + ymarg;
xd = xl/10;
yd = yl/10;

origx = 3/4*xmarg;
origy = yl + (ymarg/7);

x1=origx+0.5;
y1=origy+5;
x2=origx+0.5;
y2=origy-yl;

var ejey = document.createElementNS (esvg,"line");
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "x1", x1);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "y1", y1);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "x2", x2);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "y2", y2);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "style", "stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1");
agsvg.appendChild (ejey);

document.body.appendChild(agsvg);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ejey.setAttributeNS(null, "x1", x1);` fixes it or use `setAttribute()` instead. Read docs on [setAttributeNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttributeNS) vs [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

The function [`setAttributeNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttributeNS) takes up three arguments, you have given only two! And you are not using it for the intended use!

```
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "x1", x1);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "y1", y1);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "x2", x2);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "y2", y2);
ejey.setAttributeNS ( "style", "stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1");
```

You may need to use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) instead. Change these to:

```
ejey.setAttribute ( "x1", x1);
ejey.setAttribute ( "y1", y1);
ejey.setAttribute ( "x2", x2);
ejey.setAttribute ( "y2", y2);
ejey.setAttribute ( "style", "stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1");
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/lehoyuzebowi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using `setAttributeNS()`.  Change it to `setAttribute()` and the code will work.